# HTTP Response code 403 Issue

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, liferay

I am getting

`Http 403 code`
When I try to access that URL using my application

```
 URL url = new URL(path);
     url.openStream();
          URL url = new URL(downloadURL);

    /*URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");*/

    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"); 





    httpcon.connect();
    //url.getFile();
    InputStream is = httpcon.getInputStream();
    //InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

But I can open the URL which I am using in my application ..

Can anybody please help

I can access that URL In my browser...

That URL is from some server(local) not public.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL(path);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.getInputStream();
```

Try this way.

Comment: Tried with this one no luck

Comment: Can you paste the entire code which you are using. Also try to connect to sites like google.com instead of the application url to see whether you are getting response

Comment: The URL I am tryting to use is from local server(connected in Intra net)